# How to prove that the following sequence is a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Show that the sequence $a_n$ defined as $a_n=1+1/5+1/9+...+1/(4n-3)$ does not converge whereas $b_n$=$\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges to $0$.

While I was able to do the first part by proving that $a_n$ is a not Cauchy sequence I need help proving the second part.

My attempt: Let $p=2m$ and $q=m$, so that $p,q\geq m$.

Consider $|f_p-f_q|=|f_{2m}-f_m|=|\frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{4m+1}+\frac{1}{4m+5}...+\frac{1}{4m+4m-3}]|\leq |\frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{4m}+\frac{1}{4m}+...+\frac{1}{4m}]|= \frac{1}{4n}$

So, $|f_p-f_q|\leq \frac{1}{4mn}$

How should I proceed further?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use the fact that it is a cauchys sequence to prove convergence? It might be easier to just show convergence directly.

Comment: I know!!! But it is just for practise! I want to be able to show better that sequences are Cauchy! Also, being Cauchy it will converge. I still will have to show that it converges to $0$ tho.

Comment: this is a pretty difficult/tedious sequence to show is Cauchy by definition...

Comment: One approach would be to write $|b_n-b_m| \leq |b_n| + |b_m|$ and show that $b_n$ goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But again, this just boils down to showing convergence, and might thus not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok thank you !! Can I write that $1/4mn$<$1/m<\epsilon $ if $1/\epsilon<m$ and thus proving that it is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: There are some errors in your calculations. For instance you assumed that 
$b_{2m} = \frac{1}{n} (1+\dots+ \frac{1}{4\cdot(2m) - 3})$, but it should have been $b_{2m} = \frac{1}{2m} (1+\dots+ \frac{1}{4\cdot(2m) - 3})$. $b_m$ only depends on one variable $m$, there should be no $n$ involved.

Comment: (Not about the question itself) I have follows you for some time on the site, and I consider this a model question from you! +1. The next time you ask a question on the site, if you provide the amount of information you did here, then you will prosper on the site, not that you are already not prospering of course. Have a good day. If you need to know something more specific let me know.

Comment: Thank you Teresa for your kind words!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n \geq 2$ we have that
$$\frac{1}{4n-3} \leq \int_{n-1}^n \frac{1}{4x-3} \: dx.$$
Which means that
$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{4k-3} \leq \int_1^n \frac{1}{4x-3} \: dx= \frac{1}{4}\log(4n-3)$$
Using this we get that
$$\frac{a_n}{n} \leq \frac{1+\frac{1}{4}\log(4n-3)}{n}$$
Using for instance L'Hôpitals rule, you may prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{4}\log(4n-3)}{n} = 0,$$
and conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n = 0$. Note also that we could use the calculations above to conclude that
$$|b_n-b_m| \leq |b_n| + |b_m| \leq \frac{1+\frac{1}{4}\log(4n-3)}{n} + \frac{1+\frac{1}{4}\log(4m-3)}{m},$$
where the righthand side goes to $0$ as $n,m\rightarrow \infty$, proving that the sequence is cauchy.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
\frac{1}{4k+1}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} \\
a_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{4k+1}\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}( \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} )
$$

Answer (score 1):

Make things simple using *asymptotic equivalence*:

- $\dfrac1{4n-3}\sim_ \infty\dfrac1{4n}=\frac 14 H_n$, where $H_n$ is the general term of the (divergent) harmonic series. Therefore $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.
- As a consequence, $\dfrac{a_n}n\sim_\infty\dfrac14\dfrac 1{n^2}$, a (convergent) $p$-series, so that $\sum\limits_n\dfrac{a_n}n$ is also convergent.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't $\dfrac{a_n}{n} \sim_\infty\dfrac14\dfrac {H_n}{n}$? This is not asymptotically equivalent to the $p$-series for $p=2$. In fact, by the standard Euler-Mascheroni, $\frac{a_n}{n} \sim_\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ which converges to $0$ but the series $\sum_n \dfrac{a_n}{n}$ is divergent.

Comment: The harmonic series being $\displaystyle\sum_n\dfrac1n$, what do you obtain when you divide by $n$?

Comment: @Bernard OP writes $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{4k-3}$, but you have interpreted it as $a_n = \frac{1}{4n-3}$.